# Navigation bar won't cover the screen entirely

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I've searched around as good as I could but I couldn't seem to find an answer, it might be me who didn't use the correct keywords.

Anyways, I made a simple navbar and put it to 100% width but it won't cover the far right part of the screen. I tried using right:-5px; but it didn't help.

Here is jsfiddle so you can see my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBkma/

**CSS:**

```
 #nav {
width: 100%;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #F3B33C;
border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: -5px;
margin-right: -5px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
    <li><a id="home" href="index.html"> <img src="images/black home.png" width="28" height="28"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Database</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are moving the bar left by `5px`, therefore creating a `5px` gap on the right. What is the `left:-5px` for?

Comment: As I told Tailor, if I remove the left-5px;I get the same problem on the left.

Comment: That's due to the browser default margin on `<body>`. Set that to `margin:0` and remove all the negative positioning completely. (Also I wrote my comment before your answer comment!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need float when you are using `position: absolute;`

Secondly coming to your navigation, first of all you need reset the browser default stylesheet, you can simply use this

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

later change `left: -5px;` to `left: 0;` from `#nav` and you are good to go

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xBkma/5/)

Comment: Thanks! it fixed it, also thanks for the info. I am still pretty new at this.

Comment: Sure, yours was the first I saw that solved it. I guess the error was caused by me using both `position: absolute;` and float?

Comment: @user2168765 No, it's just you don't need float, as you are using `position: absolute;` and the real thing is that you need to use `* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}` this will reset the default browser stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Remove `left: -5px`;
and try again

Comment: If I remove the 'left-5px;'I get the same problem on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `left: -5px` you added on `#nav`
http://jsfiddle.net/xBkma/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead:

```
body{
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F3B33C;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

most browsers seem to have some padding and margin on the body so set them to zero

Comment: Glad to help. some browsers like to have some hidden padding and margin to the body or other items. it is always best to start your css with a body reset with removes the padding and margins

Answer (score 0):

You need to add box-sizing: border-box;

Like so

```
#nav {
width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box;
float: left;
margin: 0 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #F3B33C;
border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
position: absolute;
top: -1px;
left: -5px;
margin-right: -5px;
}
```

also add `body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}`

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xBkma/8/

Answer (score 0):

Remove

> position: absolute

on the nav. Position and floats contradicts each-other.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBkma/6/

```
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #F3B33C;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to remove the margin-right and left properties in nav element and set the body with margin 0.

```
body{
 margin: 0;
}
```